# PHP: Can't Set Open_basedir

Tags: php, apache, php-ini, open-basedir

I try to execute:

```
var_dump(ini_set("open_basedir",ini_get("open_basedir")));
```

with PHP and get **false**.

**Apache 2. PHP Version: 5.3.28**, it should change it from script, how i read at php.net documentation.

> Currently open_basedir is .:/data/www/vhosts/hostname:/tmp

I try to do it at local server with same OS, Apache and PHP and all ok. I try to set already setted value because i try to debug why i can't put any value there. Help, please !

Comment: PHP 5.3 was end-of-lifed like 7 years ago and `open_basedir` didn't always behave the same. Upgrade to a reasonably modern version of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically open_basedir is `no value` in php 5. (hence it may return false -- if you are setting it by getting the current value and use var_dump for display).

I suggest you to use the following to see what actual value is the open_basedir in your system:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

To further test, please try this code:

1. use ini_set to set the value;
2. return it;

```
<?php
//var_dump(ini_set("open_basedir",ini_get("open_basedir")));

ini_set("open_basedir", ".\hello");
echo "The open_basedir value is :". ini_get('open_basedir');
?>
```

Comment: no, i have it, just want configure for web app. already resolve - check all php ini variables and see privs=4

Comment: You can only make the path(s) of open_basedir more specific. It's not possible to set it to directories on the same or any above level.